# Vuejs passing data between parent child components using slots

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I can create a parent child component like this:

**Child Component**

```
Vue.component('my-child', {
    template: '<div>{{value}}</div>',
    props: {
        value: {
            type: String,
            default: ""
        }
    }
});
```

**Parent Component**

Note how the my-child component is being referenced within the parent template.

```
Vue.component('my-parent', {
    template: '<div><span>Hello</span><my-child :value="value"></my-child></div>',
    data: function () {
        return {
            value: ""
        }
    },    
});
```

I can then use that like this:

```
<my-parent :value="ABC"></my-parent>
```

The value "ABC" gets passed through correctly to the child and displays as expected.

However, what I need to be able to do is as follows (basically I've pulled the my-child out of the parent template and back into HTML. I will have a number of different my-child components that I can use inside of my-parent):

```
<my-parent :value="ABC">
    <my-child></my-child>
</my-parent>
```

I changed the parent component to use a slot like this:

```
Vue.component('my-parent', {
    template: '<div><span>Hello</span><slot :value="value"></slot></div>',
    data: function () {
        return {
            value: ""
        }
    },    
});
```

The my-child template is getting picked up and displayed but the ABC value is not getting passed through to the my-child component as I would expect.

If I do this:

```
<my-parent :value="ABC">
    <my-child :value="value"></my-child>
</my-parent>
```

the my-child binding actually looks for 'value' on the root instance and not from my-parent, which is not what I want.

How can I pass the data down via the slot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass data from a component to content in it's slot, you need to use a [scoped slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots).

In the parent component template, add the properties you want to pass to the child to the slot:

```
<div><span>Hello</span><slot :value="value"></slot></div>
```

Then in the template where the parent is used, use a `template` tag with the `scope` property.

```
<my-parent :value="ABC">
  <template scope="props">
    <my-child :value="props.value"></my-child>
  </template>
</my-parent>
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dh75xLdy/1/).

Comment: That's the way that I read the doco but it doesn't work. I did realise I was still only on vue 2.0 and this is a 2.1 feature so I upgraded to latest version but still doesn't work. It's not complaining about properties not existing or anything. it all seems to compile and run without errors. It just doesn't set the value in the child component.

Comment: @Jeff-SoftwareResults you'll have to provide some more information. This is definitely how scoped slots work.

Comment: created a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/softwareresults/fgq2utqa/1/ What I want is when I change the value at the top level vue it should go down through the two components.But at the moment I haven't had any luck even getting it to go down to the parent level :-( Getting very confused between the use of data and properties.

Comment: New fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/softwareresults/dh75xLdy/   This one uses props instead of data (did some reading :-) ). The value does pass down to the parent but it doesn't pass to the child, as per my problem above.

Comment: Thanks!! I tried various combinations like that but mustn't have hit on that one :-( If you want to update your answer I will mark it as correct. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Jeff-SoftwareResults The answer as it stands is still basically the answer to the question about how to pass a value from a parent component to content inside it's slot. I can add the contents of the fiddle if you like.

Comment: It was the bit about the binding on the slot inside the parent template that actually got it working though. If you link to the fiddle that should be ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155862/discussion-between-bert-and-jeff-software-results).

Comment: @Jeff-SoftwareResults You actually already had that part in your original question. I pulled it down into the answer and added the fiddle link.

Comment: You're right! Damn I was close :-) Marked as answered